# Writing HTML file with special characters

Tags: c#, html

I'm having a problem into writing special characters to the HTML
Basically my program is editing an HTML file and through the textbox i will replace stuff in the html file.

However I want it to be able to add characters like "ç" , "á" , "ö" etc.
I know in HTML those characters have some sort of code and I don't want to check every string manually and replace those letters to that special codes.

there must be a way to convert strings and writing them in HTML.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
string utf8_String = textBox8.Text;
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(utf8_String);
utf8_String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
content = content.Replace("{8}", utf8_String);
```

but it's not working.

Comment: If you're using UTF-8 all the way you actually don't need those HTML entities...

Comment: “Not working” is not a problem description. What happens? Show a sample of an HTML file before and after the edit.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Comment: I used the first answer as it seemed easier, I just needed to convert 4 textboxes to use special characters, thanks for your time though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `System.Web.HttpUtility` class, specifically the `HtmlEncode` and `HtmlDecode` methods to work with html strings.

The `HtmlEncode` method converts every special character in your string in the equivalent html entity; `HtmlDecode` does the exact opposite.

See the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/System.Web.HttpUtility_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to read your TextBox.Text with `HtmlAgilityPack` and after that use `HtmlEntity.Entitize` method. After that you set the `Entitize` value to the textbox. Here is little example in console application.

```
    public static void  Main(string[] args)
    {
        string html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<span>ç</span>

</body>
</html>";

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        Console.WriteLine(HtmlEntity.Entitize(doc.DocumentNode).InnerHtml);

}
```

To install Html Agility Pack you can use this in NuGet

```
PM> Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
```